# Is centre of gravity a point?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

Is the centre of earth a point? If it is so, then it should attract objects both horizontally and vertically. But, it always attracts vertically. Why is it so?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the term *vertical?* I suspect this is causing an issue.

Answer (score 5):

> If it is so, then it should attract objects both horizontally and
>   vertically

It should attract objects *radially*, i.e., along a line passing through the center of mass of both objects, and should not attract objects *tangentially*.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by "vertical":

[image]

The Earth attracts objects as a point source. However, since the word "vertical" usually means the direction of the local gravity field, things will always fall vertically - even though the (absolute) direction is different.